Can't deserialize class using XNamespace as a property
Why can't I deserialize a class when I use XNamespace as a property?
Here is the code that doesn't work:
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x= @"{""NS"": {""NamespaceName"": ""http://www.some.ns/Enterprise""}}";
        var z = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Some>(x); // --> ERROR
    }
}

public class Some(XNamespace ns){
    public XNamespace NS {get; set;} = ns;
}

HERE is the Fiddle
The error I get is:

Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace'.

If I use my own class or a value type as a parameter it works fine but for some reason it doesn't like XNamespace.

Does your own class or value type perhaps have a parameterless constructor (or zero constructors, hence an implicit parameterless constructor), or a singular parameterized constructor? Also: it seems odd to serialize XNamespace in JSON - not wrong necessarily, but definitely odd.
